# issues with ajax calls from js file in asp.net mvc 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery

A have an ajax call that executes fine when it is placed in the .cshtml file, after moving the JS to the call stopped working. I did some debuging and it apeared that right action is beeing called and it returns correct data, but I dont enter the ajax success function in the JS.

The same applies to getJSON.

and also no error message is being displayed

here is the code:

```
$.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            cache: false,
            url: url,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
               //...
            },error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                alert(xhr.status);
                    alert(thrownError);
            }
            });
        }
```

//action:

```
[HttpGet]
    public JsonResult HasUpdates()
    {
        var hasUpdates = diagnosticManager.AgentHasUpdates();
        return Json(hasUpdates, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Am I missing some thing here?

Comment: What is the value passed as url and what are the relativepaths to your view and scripts?

Comment: yes, it is a relative path, but it is formed correctly + it stops on the breakpoint in the action

Comment: Can you set a breakpoint in the error handler and see if it gets hit? If not, are there any javascript errors reported in the console?

Comment: Are you getting any script errors ? what is the value of url varibale ?

Comment: Can you include the HTML that is using the script?

Comment: @mhornfeck I'm not getting any script error messages, and there a no js error in the console.

Comment: @Shyju no I'm not getting any script error. the url variable is correct because I hit the controller action when the ajax call is invoked

Comment: put break point in your action method and see what happens

Comment: are you using a tool like [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/javascript) so that you can set breakpoints in your success/error handlers in the script?

Comment: If you add the `complete` callback, is that triggered? Are any of the [globale ajax handlers](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/global-ajax-event-handlers/) triggered?

Answer (score 1):

You may be getting success just a bit to late because of asynchronization
Use a synchronous AJAX call
look over here at the answer
[How can I get jQuery to perform a synchronous, rather than asynchronous, Ajax request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133310/how-can-i-get-jquery-to-perform-a-synchronous-rather-than-asynchronous-ajax-re)